# Flutter GMSMapView updateWithCamera crash EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE

Tags: flutter, google-maps

We're getting sporadic crashes in Google Maps running in our Flutter app on iOS. I have attached a screenshot of the stacktrace. The offending call is to `[GMSMapView updateWithCamera]`.

The setup we have is basically:

`BlocProvider<MapScreenBloc>` → `GoogleMapsWidget` → `GoogleMaps` (the last one being the actual Google Maps widget from the `google_maps_flutter` plugin)

When creating the `GoogleMaps` widget we pass it the bloc's `onMapCreated` function for the constructor parameter so that it stores the `GoogleMapController`. My guess is that at some point we're calling `_mapController.animateCamera()` but the controller has been destroyed, but I have no idea how to debug this.

Has anybody else experienced this? Any suggestions on how to debug/fix it?

[image: Crashlytics log]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that there was a bug in the iOS/Flutter implementation for Google Maps. I've created a PR for them here:
https://github.com/flutter/plugins/pull/3426

It turns out that they were repeatedly adding `addObserver:`, and when that keypath was finally updated the observer was called so many times that the OS forced the app to shut down because it thought that the app had entered an infinite loop.